# Managing SQS Queue Manually vs Lambda Trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I'm not sure if this would be better served on ServerFault or Software Engineering, willing to move this post if appropriate.

We have somewhat recently started to move some of our data processing pipeline to use queues to manage individual bits of data, whereas previously we had timed lambdas that would pull all data since last change.

While making this change, we noticed that queues didn't work quite as we had anticipated first of all - we thought lambda would just pull items off the queue as the lambdas had availability. Instead, it seems the aws managed lambda trigger grabs a chunk of messages (up to ten) and throws it at the lambda service. If lambda doesn't have availability, the message gets throttled, then replayed after a backoff time, up til our configured replay "error" limit (five). After that, it's thrown into our dead letter queue.

We see a handful of message per day end up in the dead letter queue as a result of throttling. We then throw these back into the main queue (we have a process to do so every handful of hours). However, we weren't 100% sure throttling was the reason for things being pushed over since nothing indicates why the messages are moved over - we just assumed as much because we weren't getting any error logs for those messages. We contacted Amazon support to ask about this, and they were able to actually confirm the messages were in fact "errored" as a result of throttling.

We asked further into their recommendations for this - this must be a common problem right? They first off suggested upping our replay limit, which seemed an obvious no go. Replays occur for any failure, so that would just hammer our lambdas with bad requests when they came through. Asked also if there's any way to differentiate the errors because we don't care for throttling, we'd happily let those retry a dozen times if needed - but no. The other suggestion they had was to manage the queue ourselves from our lambdas. Build our own code within our lambdas to pull messages and then delete them after processing. This seems really counter-intuitive, though - why would every AWS consumer build their own infrastructure?

So I guess my question is, is this what others are doing? Are you using the built in lambda triggers? Are you creating your own code for managing queue consumption? Do you see these sorts of throttling, or is there anything we could do differently? Are there any difference with other services to manage this?

Comment: How many concurrent executions did the lambda scale to?

Comment: "This seems really counter-intuitive, though - why would every AWS consumer build their own infrastructure?" that isn't infrastructure though, it's just a few lines of code. The same code you would write to consume messages from SQS on an EC2 server or anywhere else.

Comment: @jellycsc we are currently allowing 7 concurrent executions. Increasing this isn't the answer, though. I'm not looking for an answer to prevent us from ever getting throttled, just whether the approach of using their trigger vs doing it ourselves is correct.

Comment: @MarkB It's infra in the sense that we would have to give our lambdas receive/delete permissions, make them aware of the existence of SQS, and then build loops into them to do the message management work, which we're instead currently getting out of the lambda trigger on SQS. We could do this, it just isn't the expected approach to me, that's why I'm trying to find out if others are as well.

Comment: @shortstuffsushi Have you tried to set the batch size to 1?

Comment: @jellycsc Yes, we have used different batch sizes, not sure why a smaller batch size would be better in this case though? That would mean fewer sent to each lambda, or likely more throttling?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to handle errors in your code and manually delete messages that have succeeded. That allows you to handle poison messages without reprocessing the good messages again. Throttles shouldn't be ending up in a DLQ that often. This video from re:Invent 2020 has a good explaination of how this works. [Scalable serverless event-driven architectures with SNS, SQS & Lambda](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8zysQqxgj0I). Start at about the 20 minutes mark to get into SQS error handling.

Comment: Hmm, this is interesting and comes a little closer to answering my question, or at least perhaps help me phrase it better. We are not currently deleting out our own successful messages; we can make that change. However, we'll still have the issue of poison messages and throttles being mixed. We want poison messages to go straight to the DLQ, throttles to continue retrying forever. Would it be appropriate for us to grab our own poison messages within our lambdas, delete them from the main queue and put them into the DLQ ourselves? That way we could leave the redrive policy wide open..

Comment: Are you sure the throttles are going to the DLQ? You might consider increasing the message timeout if they are. If there is a throttle it doesn't count as a retry until it hits the point of the message timeout being less than the lambda timeout. So you might also try reducing the lambda timeout to a number that more closely matches your processing expectations.

Comment: Yes, we are sure our throttles are DLQ - I mentioned as much in the question, we weren't actually sure, so we verified with Amazon support. Changing the timeouts is something we may look into, this could potentially lessen our DLQ hits. We're talking seconds per run though, so maybe setting the timeout to ten seconds or something would be appropriate?

Comment: If you set the message timeout to say 20 seconds, and the lambda timeout to say 5, then if there is a throttle the message can retry a couple of times before being returned the the queue. That's when your redrive policy kicks in (which I believe you said was 5). That means it can get throttled probably 10-20 times before being sent to the DLQ. The odds of that happening on a single message would be pretty low.